# Битовые операции над числами

Tags: битовые-операции, java

Добрый вечер. В задачнике увидел такую задачу :

```
-7 >> 2
```

И возник вопрос. Почему результат равен -2 ? Как я понимаю, сначала нужно представить 7 в дополнительном коде (т.к. число 7 со знаком минус):

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1001
```

Затем, с помощью оператора сдвига вправо, осуществить битовую операцию:

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1110
```

И теперь мне не понятно, сколько 1-ниц учитывать при подсчете этого (аналогичных примеров) ? Здесь мы учитывали только одну 1-цу. Например в таком операции:

```
-7 << 2
```

Я также остановился на последнем этапе. Т.к. я написал представление 7 в дополнительном коде, то собственно сама битовая операция сдвига влево выглядит так:

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1110 0100
```

Здесь же почему то ответ -28. Объясните пожалуйста этот момент. Может я где то ошибся в вычислениях ?

Comment: Непонятно, что означает «сколько 1-ниц учитывать при подсчете»? Вы о каких единицах? Если о тех, что слева, то все. (Результат, кстати, будет один и тот же, по идее.)

Comment: Кстати, `1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1110 0100` и есть -28.

Comment: насчет 1 , я имею в виду , что при определении числа по его битовому представлению.

Comment: @Drylozav: ну, надо учитывать вообще все биты, конечно.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что для первого примера мы учитывали только одну 1 слева после 0 . Т.к. получается что 2(^0)*0+ 2(^1)*1. Т.к. число в минусом , то получается -2. А во втором примере до какой единицы производить подсчет ?

Answer (score 2):

-7 по модулю 7 -> 111; Инвертируем: 000; Добавляем 1: 001; Слева ставим знаковый разряд: 1001; Сдвигаем вправо на два разряда: 10; Чтобы узнать величину по модулю, вновь инвертируем: 01; добавляем 1: 10 -> 2.

Answer (score 0):

Операции сдвига в пределах разрядной сетки в допкоде равнозначны операциям умножения (если сдвиг влево) или деления с округлением по недостатку (если сдвиг вправо) на степень двойки от величины сдвига.

Поэтому `-7>>2 = -7/4 = -1, -7<<2 = -7*4 = -28.`

А тему округления отрицательных чисел по недостатку в допкоде лучше всего раскрывает пример
 `-1>>k = -1`.